# BIRT dynamic image url - cannot get access to data columns

Tags: javascript, eclipse, dataset, birt

I am trying to display different images based on data returned. I am running into the following issues

1. DataSet is not available on the image control for me to make decisions based on the column information. I am using a grid layout (no tables)... Think of a letter
2. I tried to create report level variables and assign it the value from dataset during the onFetch event. However, that assignment does not happen.

I have tried both

```
rptvar = dataSetRow["colname"]
rptvar = Row["colname"]
```

I have confirmed that onFetch event does get called using Javascript debugging (see http://www.lebirtexpert.com/wordpress/2010/08/)

Please let me know how to access dataset columns to dynamically create the image URI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a post on the BIRT world blog that should be very useful to you:
http://birtworld.blogspot.com/2010/09/birt-image-report-item.html

Kudos to Mr. Weathersby!

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get this resolved. The issues I ran into were -1)  I assumed report parameters to be same/similar to persistentglobalvariables.
2) the persistentglobalvariables understand only one datatype - string.